# Reading response content from HTTPResponseMessage

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm writing queue trigger function where I read data from queue, and send them another web service using RESTFul service. Right now, I'm testing a very simple REST api call that I only need to provide token in the header and expect very simple JSON response from the server. The JSON just contains an email address entry and that's about it. My understanding is that if I read response asynchronously, I would need to change function prototype to comply with async call. But that's not possible in Azure function app. So what's the best way to read JSON response object?

This is my attempt so far :

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static void Run(string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
   string URL = "https://api.spotlightessentials.com/api/v2/user";
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);


   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token","<Token value>");

   HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result; 

   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
        // How do I read Json response here
   }

   }
   else
   {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
   }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
```

you can do this:

```
var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<YourObjectTypeHere>();
```

Or you could also do something like this depending on your needs:

```
var responseData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseData))
{
    var responseDataObject = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectTypeHere>(responseData);
}
```

Or a combination of parts of the 2.

Comment: What can I give here instead of `YourObjectTypeHere`

Comment: You would put the type/class of the object you want the data cast to.